# Reshape a shapefile wide to long in R

Tags: r, sf

I have a shapefile (sf) object made up of polygons with polygon characteristics stored in a dataframe. This object is called `tiles`. Within the dataframe there are 12 variables indicating number of pixels that transitioned to zero forest cover by year called `loss2001, loss 2002, ... loss2012`. Each variable is indexed by a unique identifier `ID`.

```
library(sf)
tiles = st_read("ShapefileForestlossGroup1")
```

I want to reshape this shapefile dataframe so that I can produce annual spatial weights. The problem is that many reshaping options are best executed with a data table, but if I transform `tiles` into a data table, it is no longer an sf object.

As an sf object with a dataframe, I tried executing the following reshape function:

```
tiles2 = reshape(tiles, 
        direction = "long",
        varying = list(names(tiles)[1:12]),
        v.names = "numPixelsDeforested",
        idvar = "ID",
        timevar = "Year",
        times = 2001:2012)
```

But R returns the following error:

`` Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : invalid 'row.names' length In addition: Warning message: In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , v.names, value = list(loss2001 = c(0L,  : provided 2 variables to replace 1 variables ``

Could these errors be related to the fact that this is an sf object dataframe, or is the syntax just wrong?

Comment: I don't get an error if I generate a thing like this with three columns and a geometry: `tiles = st_as_sf(data.frame(x=runif(10),y=runif(10), loss2001=runif(10), loss2002=runif(10), loss2003=runif(10)), coords=1:2)` - do you? I get the *warnings* but the resultant object looks okay.

Comment: I don't get warnings if I turn the spatial data frame into a non-spatial frame by dropping the geometry and using your `reshape` code. In a pinch you could do that and then add a geometry column that is N copies of the source geometry (where N=12 for you).

Comment: When I execute this function, tiles_2 does not generate. And I am open to transforming into a non-spatial frame and transforming back when it is done, but I am worried that transferring back to an sf object will be very complicated.

Comment: Spacedman - I was able to execute the function on the tiles data you generated. But I notice that the spatial objects of this fake data is points. I have polygons.

Comment: Does it only fail if its polygons? That's an interesting discovery that we can now look into...

Comment: If I add an ID column I get the error. If I remove the ID or the geometry column I get a good reshape (with warnings). Again this is why a good reproducible example from you would be so useful! Removing the geometry then replacing it isn't that bad. I'll give that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the comments above I think we were able to scrape together a solution.

If you redefine your sf object as a data.frame, and then reshape:

```
tilesDF = as.data.frame(tilesNoNA)

tilesReshape= reshape(tilesDF, 
        direction = "long",
        varying = list(names(tilesDF)[1:12]),
        v.names = "numPixelsDeforested",
        idvar = "ID",
        timevar = "Year",
        times = 2001:2012)
```

You can then transform this long dataframe back into an sf object using:

```
tilesLong = st_as_sf(tilesReshape, sf_column_name = 'geometry')
```

The option `sf_column_name`  in `st_as_sf` is really, really handy.